# Excel dependent drop-down list from regular table

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse me if this has been answered already in other posts but I looked forever for this and could not find my scenario.  All the example I found involved static lists but I have a table that will have new entries added.  I have a table with 4 columns as shown below.

[image]

I want to create two drop downs where the first drop down is for selecting the customer name, and the second drop down is for selecting one of the 3 addresses for that particular customer.  I created an Excel table for all the data called "TBL_CUST" and then I defined a named range called "Customer" which is based on the first column of the table so the RefersTo value for the named range is "=TBL_CUST[Name]".  I am using that for the data validation for the first drop-down and that's working fine.

So now what I need to do is create a second drop down that is dependent on the value selected on the first drop down and then offer just the values for the 3 other columns of that same record.  This should not be difficult at all but I have struggled searching on how to do this with no success.  How can I setup a second validation to accomplish this? I tried using a combination of indirect and vlookup but nothing worked.

A bonus would be clearing out the second drop down field when a value is selected in the first drop down :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's how I would go about it. Let's say your data is in a2:d8 and your first dropdown is in a12. I would create another column (which you can hide or put on a different sheet) which uses this formula starting in row 2. You can then make the second dropdown data validation reference this new column.

Formula for E2:

`=INDEX($A$2:$D$8,MATCH($A$12,$A$2:$A$8,0),ROW())`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried this but it didn't work.  Also, the source value is within the table itself.

Comment: I added a photo to my answer incase that helps illustrate it

Comment: Thanks.  This is very similar to what I did as a temporary solution.  I did exactly what you did (create another 3 row table for drop down 2) except that I created a subroutine that would populate the 3 fields with the 3 addresses...and then I used a button to manually click and trigger the subroutine.  This was a temporary solution of-course.  With your suggestion I don't need the subroutine or button.

Comment: I meant to add this to my previous comment...I still think what I am trying to do should be straight forward and not require that I setup another table.  I mean somebody had to have needed to do this before and I think it should be doable with standard functions.  Anyways, thanks for the tip.  My only question left now is can I use a different function than 'MATCH'.  I don't trust that function because I tried it in VBA and found it is not case-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The template I created by adding **dependent drop-down lists on the userform** may be useful for you.

Visit [enter link description here](https://eksi30.com/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-lists-on-userform/)

[image]